# ListBoxItem selection hit test only on part of the item template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to make a ListBox behave so that only part of the item template accepts mouse click for a row selection (part with red border on the attached image).

While it is easily achievable on the DataGrid by setting IsHitTestVisible to false on the cell styles that I do not want to take part in selection I cannot get that working on the ListBox.

Setting IsHitTestVisible on the ItemContainer style to false disables selection entirely while setting IsHitTestVisible to false on some parts of the item template seems to be ignored.

```
         <!-- does not work-->
         <Border IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="24" Width="30">
           <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" (...)/>
         </Border>
```

[image: Single row]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry, the answer seems to be quite simple but done via code behind (so I am interested if you have some cleaner solutions).

on items that I do not want to take part in selection process:

```
<Border PreviewMouseDown="SwallowMouseDown" 

private void SwallowMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```